# How do I get all rows meeting specific criteria?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying, in a single query, to get an entire set of rows when only one of those rows meets certain criteria.  In the case below, I want to do a query for Mike Smith.  If I find Mike Smith has taken a test (by test_id) then I want to include all the results for that test_id.  So a successful query would return the first 7 rows.  Is this possible without running multiple queries?  Below is the example entire contents of my table.

I can't use

```
Select * where first_name = 'Mike';
```

as this will only return Mike's test scores;

I don't know how to select all test scores (for multiple tests) when I have a result for Mike.

```
+------------+------------+-----------+-------+------+
| test_id    | first_name | last_name | class | rank |
+------------+------------+-----------+-------+------+
| 1          | John       | Doe       | 2012  | 1    |
+------------+------------+-----------+-------+------+
| 1          | Jack       | Smith     | 2014  | 50   |
+------------+------------+-----------+-------+------+
| 1          | Mike       | Smith     | 2014  | 60   |
+------------+------------+-----------+-------+------+
| 2          | Mike       | Smith     | 2014  | 70   |
+------------+------------+-----------+-------+------+
| 2          | John       | Smith     | 2014  | 80   |
+------------+------------+-----------+-------+------+
| 3          | Jake       | Smith     | 2014  | 80   |
+------------+------------+-----------+-------+------+
| 3          | Mike       | Smith     | 2014  | 90   |
+------------+------------+-----------+-------+------+
| 4          | Jake       | Smith     | 2014  | 78   |
+------------+------------+-----------+-------+------+
```

Comment: which query did you try? and why show only the first 7 rows? the 8th row does not require to show? I thought you say *If I find Mike Smith has taken a test (by test_id) then I want to include all the results for that test_id*

Comment: forgive me.  I'll edit my question.  What I'm showing is the hypothetical total contents of the table.  And I'm trying to write a query selecting all test_ids where say first_name = Mike.

Comment: Would you consider subqueries as multiple queries?

Comment: I wasn't familiar with how to use sub queries, with the assistance below though I think i get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `EXISTS` clause, eg

```
SELECT * FROM `test_table` a WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM `test_table` b
    WHERE first_name = 'Mike'
    AND last_name = 'Smith'
    AND b.test_id = a.test_id
)
```

Alternatively, you can `INNER JOIN` the table to itself, eg

```
SELECT a.* FROM `test_table` a
INNER JOIN `test_table` b
    ON a.test_id = b.test_id
WHERE b.first_name = 'Mike' AND b.last_name = 'Smith'
```

Demo here - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c8646/1

Comment: Hi Phil.  I can get both to work, is there an advantage to using one over the other?  Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @Basballguy I'm not really sure. The execution plans on SQLFiddle look similar. You'd really need to profile them yourself

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you're after:

```
SELECT * 
FROM test_scores
WHERE test_id IN
(
    SELECT test_id
    FROM test_scores
    WHERE first_name = 'Mike' AND last_name = 'Smith'
    GROUP BY test_id
)
```

Note: I just assumed the table name was 'test_scores'

Comment: Don't quote your table names

Comment: Thanks, removed those. :)